# overriding <cookie-config><max-age> Tomcat config in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, cookies

there is a config about cookie max age in tomcat that i want to override it in my spring application. the config is as below:

```
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config><max-age>120</max-age></cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

I already tried this config in application.yml and changed the max age to 600 but the cookie max age remains 120.

```
server:
  error:
    include-stacktrace: never
    whitelabel.enabled: false
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        max-age: 600
```

and also found below config which seems to be deprecated:

```
  session:
    cookie:
      max-age: 600
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the code below -

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.domain=.XXXX.com
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.path=/
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=600
```

Comment: for more details click on this link -  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

Comment: I added application.properties file into project and applied your recommended configs into it and tested it but cookie max age is still 2 minutes. i already have to mention i put domain to localhost. thanks

Comment: plz add that line also and try - server.servlet.session.timeout=15m

Comment: added session timeout and set it to 30 minutes and tested it. but doesn't work. thanks

Comment: can you plz configure cookie on tomcat server level and try.

Comment: I already tried changing it on tomcat server level and it works fine. the cookie age changes to 10 minutes. other attributes like secure works on this level fine too. but when i try to override it from application file it won't override tomcat configurations.